# Lattice, xyplot, 2 time series on same graph (overlay)

Tags: r, time-series, lattice

I want to plot two time series on the same graph, using xyplot.

Here is an example of what I mean using ts.plot()

```
a1 = ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4)
a2 = a1+3
ts.plot(a1,a2)
```

I have tried

`xyplot(merge(a1,a2))`

which returns an error, and I have tried

```
xyplot(merge(as.xts(a1),as.xts(a2)))
```

which plots them in different panels, not on the same panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your two time series objects using `cbind` (or, alternatively, `ts.union`). Then set the `superpose` argument in `xyplot` to `TRUE`:

```
xyplot(cbind(a1, a2), superpose = TRUE)
```

[image: time series plots superposed]

Short clarification: There is an S3 method for `xyplot` that handles `ts` (time series) objects. This method (`xyplot.ts`) gets called when the `x` argument to `xyplot` is a time series object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as.layer()`function from `latticeExtra`. It puts the 2nd plot as a layer over the 1st one. Therefore you have to make sure that the limits for x and y-axis are suitable. Most parameters are by default taken from the first plot. For your example the y axis has to be set manually with the `ylim=c()`key within the first plot.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

a1 <- ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4)
a2 <- a1+3

ymax <- max(c(a1,a2)) * 1.05
ymin <- min(c(a1,a2)) * 1.05

xyplot(a1, ylim=c(ymin,ymax)) + as.layer(xyplot(a2, col="black"))
```